# jQuery's slideUp function not working properly for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8vzT/).

My goal is to have a button to remotely slide up the image via a button, but instead it becomes small .

Anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the image inside a container with `overflow: hidden` set to it, so that the browser doesn't resize the image itself and cause the distortion of the aspect ratio.

HTML

```
<div class="le_map_container"> <!-- overflow: hidden on this element -->
    <img src="http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/wp-content/files_flutter/1330095469Untitled-5.jpg" height="200" class="le_map"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.tour_map').click(function() {        
    $(".le_map_container").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8vzT/9/)

Comment: Thank you Rory! Quick question though: the idea on my website is for the image to come over my button via position absolute when I press the button. How do I make the image disappear when my mouse leaves the image hover instead of having to click the button again?

Comment: @imjp You'd need to call `slideUp()` on the image on the `mouseleave()` event.

Answer (score 3):

The image element is trying to keep its aspect ratio, since you only specified a `height` and not a `width`.

Adding `width="200px"` solves your problem. You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8vzT/1/).

Comment: This still causes the image aspect ratio to become distorted as it slides up.

Answer (score 0):

The slideToggle method changes the height of the element. But I think because you slideToggle the image tag directly, the width is changed along with the height to keep the ratio.

Try setting explicitly a width you your image to the width stays.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/SrXNL/)**